# Lost database wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, hosting

I renewed hosting but forgot to renew databases. now the database has expired and assiduity tells us we have deleted databases and can not retrieve server-side data.
now I can not get into the backend of my site.
Does anyone know what to do?
thanks

Comment: 1) recreate the database and 2) restore from mysqldump backup.

Comment: If you didn't keep backups, and your host didn't keep backups, there's not that much you can do. You might be able to use Google's cache to (very manually) retrieve the text of your posts.